# Multiple definition of variable

Tags: c++

Here's my code:

**main.cpp**

```
#include "foo.h"

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

**foo.h**

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo();
    int bar;
}

#endif
```

**foo.cpp**

```
#include "foo.h"

Foo::Foo()
{
    bar = 3;
}
```

Compiling this gives me the following error:

`multiple definition of 'bar'`

But I have include guards around the header file which defines `bar`, therefore how can it be defined more than once?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's down to the missing semicolon at the end of the class *declaration* `foo` in `foo.h`.

That's confusing the compiler (it seems to be attempting to parse your constructor definition as the name of an object of type `foo`).

C++ ain't Java you know!

Comment: Ah yes, thanks! I wish my compiler had noticed that simple error though rather than just getting confused...

Comment: Some compilers are indeed better at warning you of this than others.

Comment: Actually, I've now come across another issue with my code which is very similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38974026/multiple-definitions-of-variable-in-global-scope